# how to find duplicate contacts in list View

Tags: java, android

I have developed app that access contacts via Content Resolver.It show all the contacts in one list view even duplicate contacts also shown on same list view  But i want to show duplicate contacts in other list view so that i can delete them according to my wish easily. Kindly Help me. Ill be thankful to you cordially .here is sample code.

```
package com.example.contentprovider;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.MatrixCursor;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Cursor Adapter for storing contacts data
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

// List View Widget
ListView lvContacts;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Init ListView
    lvContacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvContacts);

    // Initialize Content Resolver object to work with content Provider
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    // Read Contacts
    Cursor c = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null,
            null);


    // Attached with cursor with Adapter
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c,
            new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME },
            new int[] { R.id.lblName });

    // Display data in listview
    lvContacts.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you add all contact into list and remove duplicate by hashset . because hashset does not allow duplicate elements.

```
psedo code:---
1. Once get all object like name,phone number from contentResolver then add those string objet into arraylist 
2. After that pass taht list to hashset so duplicate will be removed.

ArrayList<String> values=new ArrayList<String>();
HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>();
hashSet.addAll(values);
values.clear();
values.addAll(hashSet);
it might be helpful for you .
```

Comment: i did not understand this code and where to put it . kindly modify my code.

Comment: I modified my answer

Comment: Dear Actually m totally beginner of Android , i dont know how to add object to string so thats why i asked you to modify my code. Code is given above. Thanx again

Answer (score 0):

**find Duplicate Contact from Contact ArrayList**

```
private ArrayList<PhoneContact> findDuplicates1(ArrayList<PhoneContact> phoneContacts) {

    int i;
    ArrayList<PhoneContact> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    PhoneContact contact;
    int count ;
    for (i = 0; i < phoneContacts.size() ; i++){
        String contact1 = phoneContacts.get(i).getContactNumber();
        contact = phoneContacts.get(i);

        count = 0;
        list2.add(contact);

        for (int j = i+1 ;j < phoneContacts.size() ; j++ )
        {
            String contact2 = phoneContacts.get(j).getContactNumber();
            if (contact1.equals(contact2) || contact1.equals("+91"+contact2) || contact2.equals("+91"+contact1)){
                phoneContacts.get(j).setCheck(true);
                PhoneContact contact11 = phoneContacts.get(j);
                count = 1;
                list2.add(contact11);
                phoneContacts.remove(j);
            }
        }
        if (count == 0)
        {
            list2.remove(contact);
            count=0;
        }
    }
    return list2;
}
```

*here Just pass your Contact ArrayList and return list Of Duplicate contact*